# React element rendered as an object

Tags: reactjs

The element "not__uploaded" is rendered as [object Object]. I am fairly new to React and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong here.

'responseRecieved' is a boolean which tracks whether the api call was made or not.

```
ce('div', {
    className: 'response__done'
},
ce('p', {
    className: ''
}, 'Upload results: '),
`${responseRecieved ?
   response.not_uploaded.map(({ msg, post_category }) =>
                ce('div', {className: 'not__uploaded clearfix'},
                  ce('p', {className: ''},
                    msg,
                    ' for post with',
                    post_category[0],
                  ),
                ))
             : ''}`
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
`${responseRecieved ?
   response.not_uploaded.map(({ msg, post_category }) =>
                ce('div', {className: 'not__uploaded clearfix'},
                  ce('p', {className: ''},
                    msg,
                    ' for post with',
                    post_category[0],
                  ),
                ))
             : ''}`
```

This whole piece of code is wrapped inside a template string ``, so the end result will be a string.

`response.not_uploaded.map` is bound to return an array. Judgning by your current output from the question, it returns an array with 2 objects insdie. This array with 2 objects is in turn rendered inside a string template, which is basically coercing the array to a string. The default behavior of an array being coerced to string is the call of `toString()` on that array. Default `toString()` implementation for arrays is calling `Array.join(',')`. This is why your objects come out as a string sepparated by a comma character.

Finally, both objects inside the array are also being coerced to string values (`toString()`is called on each of them). Apparently none of your objects has a `toString()` implementation, so javascript is just defaulting to `"object Object"`

Comment: I just removed the template string and it worked. Thanks.